# Prefetching returning empty values for some object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-database

Assume these two models.

```py
class Folder(model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    files = models.ManyToManyField('File')

class File:
   path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

First I was fetching the folders and while looping over them fetching the files with distinct path

```py
folders = Folder.objects.all()

for folder in folders:
    files_with_distinct_path = folder.files.distinct('path').order_by('path')
```

but this suffers from N+1 problem, So I tried prefetching the files while fetching all the folders.

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

folders = Folder.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'files', queryset=File.objects.distinct('path').order_by('path'), to_attr='distinct_files'
    )
)
```

but it turns out now there objects with empty `distinct_files` which is not the correct result, these objects have files but after prefetching the result is empty only for few objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try ordering the `File` queryset by `folder` first so that you get distinct paths per folder

```
queryset=File.objects.order_by('folders', 'path').distinct('path')
```